# React + Meteor / 3 party jQuery libraries requires full page refresh before they function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I have a react + meteor application, and I'm facing an issue initializing third party jQuery libraries came in with the theme I'm using for my project.

Upon successful login I get redirected to (Dashboard) (3rd party libraries doesn't load).

However If I perform Full page re-fresh after login, all libraries works fine.

I'm wondering if someone has encountered such issue, your suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getScript` method of jQuery. It will asynchronously load the script and you can also perform any operation when it is successfully loaded.  Following snippet might help.

```
componentDidUpdate(){
  let context = this;
  $.getScript(<script source>, function(){
    // this is a callback function called upon the script loading is finished
  });
}
```